# How can I reduce the amount of data in a polars DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a csv file with a size of 28 GB, which I want to plot. Those are way too many data points obviously, so how can I reduce the data? I would like to merge about 1000 data points into one by calculating the mean. This is the sturcture of my DataFrame:

| Time in seconds | Force in N |
| --- | --- |
| **f64** | **f64** |
| 0.0 | 2310.18 |
| 0.0005 | 2313.23 |
| 0.001 | 2314.14 |

I thought about using `groupby_dynamic`, and then calculating the mean of each group, but this only seems to work when using datetimes? The time in seconds is given as a float however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also group by an integer column to create groups of size `N`:

> In case of a `groupby_dynamic` on an integer column, the windows are defined by:
>
> `“1i”` # length 1
>
> `“10i”` # length 10

We can use [`.int_range()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.int_range.html) to add an integer row count to group on:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"force": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]})

(df.with_columns(row_nr = pl.int_range(0, pl.count()))
   .groupby_dynamic(
      index_column = "row_nr",
      every = "2i" 
   )
   .agg("force")
)
```

```py
shape: (4, 2)
┌────────┬────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ force      │
│ ---    ┆ ---        │
│ i64    ┆ list[str]  │
╞════════╪════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ ["A", "B"] │
│ 2      ┆ ["C", "D"] │
│ 4      ┆ ["E", "F"] │
│ 6      ┆ ["G"]      │
└────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: What is `pl`? `pandas.DataFrame` has no attribute `with_columns`

Comment: @jlgarcia [polars](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars)

Comment: This worked really well, thank you! However, my kernel crashes when using the full dataset (propably due to memory?) using chuncks of 1000i. Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: solved this by using `pl.read_csv_batched()`, which had a small learning curve itself :D Works great now though :)

Answer (score 0):

Another version, using/assuming `pandas dataframes` to reduce your dataframe's shape using N-points mean:

```
# 1000 = how many points you want to aggregate
s = (df.index.to_series() / 1000).astype(int) 
df.groupby(s).mean()
```